# Writing data to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I can't seem to read or write data to firebase. I do have the rules on true. I've even tried the simple code given in firebase and it still won't write anything

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Games");

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.btnSidebar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String id=  myRef.push().getKey();
                String name ="Cyberpunk 2077";
                String date ="April 16, 2020";
                String company="CD Projekt Red";
                String platform = "XBOX, PS4, PC";
                String description = "some text";
                GameList games = new GameList(name, date, company, platform, description);
                myRef.child(id).setValue(games);
            }
        });
```

Here is my data code

```
public class GameList {
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private String company;
    private String platform;
    private String description;

    public GameList(){

    }

    public GameList(String name, String date, String company, String platform, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.company = company;
        this.platform = platform;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener to the set value operation to see what the error?

Comment: yes I have. For some reason the data doesn't update, none of the coding works